# Hyper-V RedHat Guest OS

Tags: hyper-v

I installed RedHat as a guest, and it installed fine.
However, I do not have a connection to the internet, I bring up a browser and it cannot surf anywhere.
Would someone be able to give me some things to check/do to figure out the issue?

Comment: what does ifconfig in the guest say?

Comment: what version of hyper-v and do you have the newest integration components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your Redhat VM Settings, remove the existing network adapter and then select "Legacy network adapter"

You should get network / internet then provided that legacy adapter is bound to a "Virtual network of type "External".

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Rihatum said:

> Go into your Redhat VM Settings, remove the existing network adapter and then select "Legacy network adapter"
>
> You should get network / internet then provided that legacy adapter is bound to a "Virtual network of type "External".

I would add to that by saying:  Don't delete the old network adapter, just add a "legacy" one.  And now use your new-found Internet connectivity to get the Hyper-V Integration Components for Linux.  Install them in your VM.  You should now have two paths to networking, one slow "legacy" one and one fast one.  Now go and delete the "legacy" one to leave only fast networking.